# Two time points, control and experimental groups: What design is it?

Tags: terminology, methodology, statistics

I managed to get myself confused on this one. 
So I am planning to conduct an experiment within an organization. I want to explore effects of recognition on people's motivation. Recognition will be in a form of personalised recognition letter. Experimental group will receive the letter, control group won't.

I wanted to measure levels of intrinsic and extrinsic motivation in both groups prior to the intervention, and then post-intervention.

- my IVs: intervention/no intervention; time period 1/time period 2
- my DV: motivation

Questions:

- is it independent groups design and I will need factorial ANOVA? Or time doesn't count as a variable?
- or maybe I don't need to measure motivation levels before at all?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is purely statistical and, therefore, is a better fit for [stats.se].

Answer (score 1):

You could call it a 2 by 2 mixed design where condition is a between-subjects factor and has two levels (intervention, no intervention) and time is a within-subjects factor and has two levels (time 1 and time 2).

Regarding how to analyse this data, check out this question on [Best practice when analysing pre-post treatment-control designs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs).